# How to save variables from any type into UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: swift, storage, nsuserdefaults

Here we have a variable named "Data". it is from the type "memorySTR" which is self defined. this variable must be saved to UserDefaults when the app is shutting down and load when app runs again . here is the code .

```
//Here loads the data when the app runs :
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data") != nil {Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data") as! MemorySTR} 
//Here saves the data when necessary :
UserDefaults.standard.set( Data ,forKey: "Data")
```

but unfortunately the type "memorySTR" is not accepted to the UserDefaults , so it gives an error. Also, the type "memorySTR" is not a simple type, that means we can not save its properties one by one. so how can we save that variable to permanent storage ?
solve this problem in a code with the SIMPLES and the SHORTEST way please.

Comment: This sure sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSKeyArchiver` and implement `NSCoder` protocol in your `MemorySTR` class and then doing this

**Implementing NSCoder Protocol**

```
required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
       //***decode your attributes here**//
    }

extension MemorySTR : NSCoding
{ 
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
          //***encode your attributes here**//
    }
}
```

***Saving and Loading your custom object from UserDefaults***

```
func saveData(object: MemorySTR){
    let myEncodedObject  =  NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myEncodedObject, forKey:"memoryStr")
}

func loadMemorySTRObject() -> MemorySTR?{
    let myEncodedObjet = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"memoryStr")

    if myEncodedObjet != nil {
        return  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: myEncodedObjet as! Data) as! MemorySTR
    }else{
        return  nil
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately no , memory STR is a stucture , its is not a class .

Comment: @Arman if you need save to UserDefaults then you MemorySTR should be an class instead, but if you want to get deeper understanding read this https://medium.com/@ryuichi/swift-struct-nscoding-107fc2d6ba5e